# How to access Confluence page title and body from inside using plugin java code?

Tags: plugins, export, confluence

I am trying to create my custom plugin which can help me extract out the Confluence contents in XML format. I did analyse the XML Export option under Advanced, however the 
XML it generates is quite cluttered with data i do not need.
My aim is to create an XML something like

```
 <Title>Page Title :Test Title</Title>
 <Body>[CDATA]Page Body...[CDATA]</Body>
 <Version>1.0</Version>
```

So i have added my custom link in the advanced tab named Freeway Export like http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/4519/pagektg.jpg .
 I have my custom Java class configured which is called on the Submit event seen in the UI .

```
public String doDefaultXmlFreeway() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("The call to doDefaultXmlFreeway has been made ");
        exportType = ImportExportManagerExtended.TYPE_FREEWAY;
        System.out.println("The contents to be exported >> " + getContentToBeExported().size());
        System.out.println("The contents available >> " + getContentTree().size());
        return doDefault();
   }
```

The console gave out the ouput like this:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] The call to doDefaultXmlFreeway has been made
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] The contents to be exported >> 2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] The contents available >> 3
```

There were 3 contents listed in my space as seen in the UI image.If i checked 2 of the contents checkbox; the getContentToBeExported() showed the appropriate number.

Now my next step is to somehow acquire the title and body of the pages so that i can use it for the xml conversion.
        Can i get the title and body details from the contenTree in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Angela,

You seem to be extending class [ExportSpaceAction](http://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/importexport/actions/ExportSpaceAction.html).

`getContentTree().getPages()`

is the api you are looking to get a hold of the pages. From there getting the tile and body should be easy from the javadocs.

Adil